# Open mail-links with gmail in Chrome 9

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

it happens quite often, that I click a link over a persons name, just to see that it launches the default mail client of my system. I thought it would be a normal link, but it was a "mailto:"-link.

I would like Chrome to start gmail, not my default email client.

For Firefox, I had only to paste this in the URL-Bar:

`javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s","GMail")`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Chrome 9.

I have found this [tutorial for Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/set-gmail-as-default-mail-client-in-ubuntu/), but I would like a solution in Chome. If it is only in Chrome, I can sync the settings. (So [How do I make mailto: links open gmail in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/32493/how-do-i-make-mailto-links-open-gmail-in-ubuntu) doesn't fit)

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2aad08042607a4eb&hl=en could be related to my problem, but there is no answer.

**Gnome:**

```
$ gnome-default-applications-properties
```

set Email-Client to

```
gnome-open https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link:

> **Making Gmail your default mail application**
>
> http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966

Comment: Thanks, I just had to install this extension from Google: [Send from Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc). The icon (which I don't need) can be hidden with a right click on it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Mailto:Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgkkmcknielgdhebimdnfahpipajcpjn).  I've been using it for a few weeks now without any problems.

Comment: Just installed this plug-in on Chrome and works flawlessly. The Gmail notifier in the other post is pretty old from the looks of it.